# find all integers $n$ such that $2^{n-1}*n+1$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Clearly $n=0$
and i found that also $n=5$ gives a perfect square
And By representing the two functions , we found that there are only two solutions that are $n=0,5$

But I don't know how to prove that using elementary number theory.

Comment: Hint: if $n 2^{n-1}  + 1 = m^2$ it follows that $n 2^{n-1}  = m^2-1=(m-1)(m+1)$. What can you say about the factors $m-1$ and $m+1$?

Comment: @RonaldBlaak mmmm I don't know 
they are both even and on of them is divisible by 4

Comment: Yes, for $n \geq 4$ they are both even and differ by 2, hence one is 2 times an odd number, while the other contains all the remaining factors of 2. From that information you can show that for $n>5$ no such solution will be possible. Unfortunately, the answer is already provided below.

Comment: Tnx a lot for this 
Sincerly I didn't understand the answer below hahaha @RonaldBlaak

Comment: because the solution says that it is impossible only for $n\ge 9$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robert Israel has already provided a nice answer, but it seems that you don't get it.

The idea in this answer is the same as the one in his answer. One can make his argument a bit simpler.

Let us prove that $2^{n-1}n+1$ is not a perfect square for $n\gt 5$.

Suppose that there exist positive integers $n,a$ such that $n\gt 5$ and
$$2^{n-1}n+1=a^2$$
Then, we have
$$2^{n-1}n=(a-1)(a+1)$$

Since LHS is even, RHS has to be even. Since $a-1$ and $a+1$ have the same parity, we see that both $a-1$ and $a+1$ have to be even. Therefore, there exist *positive* integers $p,q,r,s$ such that
$$a-1=2^pr,\qquad a+1=2^qs,\qquad p+q=n-1,\qquad rs=n$$ 
Suppose here that $p\ge 2$ and $q\ge 2$. Then, since both $a-1$ and $a+1$ are divisible by $4$, it follows that $2=(a+1)-(a-1)\ge 4$ which is impossible.

So, we have either $p=1$ or $q=1$.

If $p=1$, then $a+1=2^qs=2^{n-2}s\ge 2^{n-2}$ and $a-1\ge 2^{n-2}-2$ to have
$$2^{n-1}n\ge 2^{n-2}(2^{n-2}-2)\implies 2^{n-3}\le n+1$$

If $q=1$, then $a-1=2^pr=2^{n-2}r\ge 2^{n-2}$ and $a+1\ge 2^{n-2}+2$ to have
$$2^{n-1}n\ge 2^{n-2}(2^{n-2}+2)\implies 2^{n-3}\le n-1\implies 2^{n-3}\le n+1$$

So, in either case, it follows from the following lemma that $n\le 5$ which contradicts $n\gt 5$. $\quad\blacksquare$

**Lemma** : If $n$ is an integer such that $2^{n-3}\le n+1$, then $n\le 5$.

*Proof for the lemma* :

It is sufficient to prove that if $n\ge 6\in\mathbb Z$, then $2^{n-3}\gt n+1$.

For $n=6$, we get $2^{n-3}=8\gt 7=n+1$.

Supposing that it holds for $n$ gives
$$2^{(n+1)-3}=2\cdot 2^{n-3}\gt 2(n+1)=(n+1)+1+n\gt (n+1)+1\qquad\square$$

Comment: okay thanks
 I didn't understand the solution of Israel

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $2^{n-1} n + 1 = x^2$ with $n > 5$.  Then $2^{n-1} n = (x-1)(x+1)$ is a product of two integers that differ by $2$.  Corresponding to this we must have $x-1 = 2^k u$ and $x+1 = 2^{n-1-k} v$ where $uv = n$.  Now $\min(k,n-1-k) \le 2$, otherwise $x+1$ and $x-1$ would differ by at least $4$.
If $k \le 2$, $x+1 \ge 2^{n-3}$ and $x-1 \ge 2^{n-3}-2$ so
$$2^{n-1} n  =  (x+1)(x-1) \ge 2^{2n-6} - 2^{n-2} $$
which simplifies to 
$$ n + 1/2 \ge  2^{n-5}$$
and it is easy to see that this is false if $n \ge 9$.
Similarly if $n-1-k \le 2$, $ x-1 \ge 2^k \ge 2^{n-3}$ and
$x+1 \ge 2^{n-3}+2$ so
$$ 2^{n-1} n  \ge 2^{2n-6} + 2^{n-2}$$
and this is false if $n$ is too big.

Comment: But i need to prove that $n=0,5$

Comment: @user600785 Can't you just work out that part on your own?  This answer gives almost everything, except one last easy step.

Comment: @Zvi Ok tnx
I will just try some values of $n$

Comment: I have a small doubt. In the inequality $min(k,n-1-k)\leq 2$, shouldn't it be $min(k,n-1-k)\lt 2$. I used $p= 2^k u$ and $q = 2^{n-1-k} v$. Now 

$$p-q = 2^{min(k,n-k-1)}(s-t)$$

Since, $(s-t)\geq 1$, $p-q\geq 2^{min(k,n-k-1)}$, therefore for the difference to be $2$, $min(k,n-k-1) \leq 1$

Comment: @SauhardSharma could someone kindly explain how we are able to deduce $\min(k, n-1-k)$?

Comment: We're trying to figure out what the min(k,n−1−k) value can be? So for that, we have made this equation. Now for p-q to be 2, the power of 2 in the inequality must be 1

Comment: @SauhardSharma I am confused about the "otherwise $x+1$ and $x-1$ would differ by at least 4" argument. I understand this when $u=v$, but why can't we adjust $u$ and $v$ such that they keep the difference at 2?

Comment: $x-1 = 2^k u$.  If $k \ge 2$, this is divisible by $4$.  $x+1 = 2^{n-1-k} v$,  If $n-1 -k \ge 2$, this is divisible by $4$.  Two distinct numbers divisible by $4$ would differ by at least $4$.